# How to get last row of repeating column in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table as follow. I want to run a query to select the data from the table using `php` in which if `date column` is repeated then I want to take only last row of that date

```
id     Date          start   end    publish
1   04-Nov-2015     1000    1300    0
4   04-Nov-2015     2100    3500    0
5   05-Nov-2015     1500    3000    0
```

like for the below table, When I run the query then the result should come:

```
4   04-Nov-2015     2100    3500    0
5   05-Nov-2015     1500    3000    0
```

When I run the query

```
$select = mysql_query("select * from `entry` Group by `date`") or die(mysql_error());
```

Then It shows the first row of repeating table, What should I modify in the query that the result should show the last row of repeating colum

Comment: What do you mean, the last row? Which row is it, and based on what condition?

Comment: if id is auto_increment you can use Select * from (Select * from entry order by date,id desc) x group by x.date

Comment: thanks @Undefined_variable it worked

Comment: @RohitashvSinghal please accept the answer so that question will be closed

Comment: Be aware that the old mysql_* extension which you're using is deprecated in version 5.5 of PHP (the current version) and is being removed from version 7 (the next version). You need migrate over to using either the mysqli_* extension or PDO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select * from (Select * from entry order by date,id desc) x group by x.date
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query :-

```
select * from( select * from entry order by id DESC ) new Group by date
```

Comment: it is also giving the first row

Comment: select * from(
select * from `entry` order by id DESC
) new Group by `date`

Comment: try this query @RohitashvSinghal

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with this approach:

```
$select = mysql_query("select * from `entry` Group by `date`" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try inner query, I'm not sure following will work exactly as I cant test that now, but for getting result you have to use inner query. Inner query help me to get expected result in my case.

```
SELECT *
FROM entry p
WHERE id =
  (SELECT max(id) FROM entry p2
   WHERE p2.id = p.id)
GROUP BY p.date
ORDER BY p.id DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

This query will work for you:

```sql
create TABLE test (id INT PRIMARY KEY, tdate DATE, start INT);

SELECT t1.* FROM test as t1
LEFT JOIN test as t2
  ON (t1.tdate = t2.tdate AND t1.id < t2.id)
WHERE t2.id IS NULL;
```